# Почему НН в "отработанность"?

Tags: орфография

Почему слово "обработанность" пишется с двумя Н?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При выборе количества НН нужно **проверить морфемный состав слова**:

От/работ/а/ть — от/работ/а/нн/ый — от/работ/а/нн/ость.

Отработать — **приставочный глагол совершенного вида**, поэтому для образования причастия используется суффикс НН. Две буквы НН сохраняются в существительном, образованном с помощью суффикса  ОСТЬ (на гласную).

Answer (score 1):

Существительное "отработанность" происходит от причастия "отработанный" (что сделанный?), а подобные причастия пишутся с двумя Н в отличие от прилагательных (сравните: *"жареный пирожок"* — прилагательное и *"жаренный в масле карась"* — причастие).